# Working with XLSWRITE in MATLAB: How do I delete empty cells?

Tags: excel, matlab, cell

I am generating an Excel file through MATLAB and I have empty cells in the middle of it. Here is the code I am using to initialize an empty matrix:

```
newfile = cell(5,5);
[newfile{:}] = deal('');
[newfile{:}] = deal(' ');
```

I then do some processing and write the data to a file using XLSWRITE. The spreadsheet ends up having some empty cells and some data. Is there a command by which I can delete the empty rows, without effecting the rows which have data in them?

Another question:

Is there a way to append onto this Excel file? I run this file everyday and would like to automatically add data rather than manually copying and pasting everyday.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Addition to above question:

If my output file looks like

> 1.8        3           -4.7
>
> 1.87   3.9 -5.8
>
> 1.84   2.8 -4.3
>
> 2  3.2 -4.7
>
> 2  3.7 -6
>   2  3.6 -5.2
>   3  4.3 -6.5
>
> 13 4.2 13.1
>
> 12 3.5 -6.3
>
> 1.65   1.9 -4.4

So how do i delete the empty rows when its not in cell as cellfun does not work for this

Comment: I'm curious... why do you deal an empty string and then a space to the cells? The first deal statement is unnecessary since the cell values are just overwritten by the second deal statement.

Comment: related question. anyway other than creating a empty string.  IS there a command like 
zeros(x,y)  which creates blank cells , without having to use num2cell conversions in everystep after ?
something like newfile=blank(x,y) 
which would give me a matrix with blanks of dimension x,y

Comment: @AP: You could do something like this: `newfile = repmat({' '},x,y);`

Comment: The solution u gave 

newfile = newfile(~all(cellfun('isempty',newfile) ,2),:)  works like a chram for the above question when i had empty cells.
How do i modify for the case when i have just  blanks and use 

newfile = repmat({' '},x,y); to generate my initial file?

thanks

Comment: @AP: I updated my answer to address your additional problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the first part of your question right, you want to remove any rows in your `newfile` cell array that contain only empty cells. You can do this using the function [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) to find empty cells, using the function [ALL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/all.html) to find the rows that contain all empty cells, and then using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1) to remove those rows:

```
>> newfile = cell(5,5);  %# Empty cell array
>> newfile(:) = {''};    %# A different way to assign values without DEAL
>> newfile([1 2 4 5]) = {'a'}  %# Make some non-empty cells

newfile = 

    'a'     ''     ''     ''     ''
    'a'     ''     ''     ''     ''
     ''     ''     ''     ''     ''
    'a'     ''     ''     ''     ''
    'a'     ''     ''     ''     ''

>> emptyIndex = cellfun('isempty',newfile)  %# Logical index of empty cells

emptyIndex =

     0     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1

>> newfile = newfile(~all(emptyIndex,2),:)  %# Removes 3rd row

newfile = 

    'a'     ''     ''     ''     ''
    'a'     ''     ''     ''     ''
    'a'     ''     ''     ''     ''
    'a'     ''     ''     ''     ''
```

**EDIT:** If you initialize your cell array `newfile` with blank spaces (`' '`) instead of empty strings (`''`) you will have to change the way you compute `emptyIndex` in the above code. The [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) argument `'isempty'` should be changed to `@(x) strcmp(x,' ')` to get the same results.

---

With respect to your second question, you can specify in your call to [XLSWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html) the sheet and row/column range in the file where you want to add your data. If you add to the file once per day, the easiest solution may be to add a new sheet with the date as the name. The following writes the data in `M` to the file `fileName`, adding a new sheet that is named with the current date and time:

```
xlswrite(fileName,M,datestr(now));
```

Comment: for adding to the excel file. I have 4 files and i name them as 
M_2010_03_11.xls , N_2010_03_11.xls and so on.
How do i merge to a one file by name lets say M.xls , N.xls  by your method, I cannot call by row/column range as they are diff each day and if i manually look , i might as well copy and paste ( like i am doing direcly onto excel manually )

Comment: @AP: I'm not totally sure what you mean. It sounds like you already have a bunch of separate Excel files that you want to merge into one, whereas my solution above is assuming you already have one file and you're adding a new days worth of data to it as a new sheet. To combine your existing files, I guess you could loop over them, calling XLSREAD to get the raw data (i.e. `[junk,junk,raw] = xlsread(fileName);`) and then writing the raw data to separate sheets in one file.

Comment: @gnoice  , No you understood me right at the first time. I run this program everyday based on my daily files. And i generate 4 files . It would be good , if the new 4 files gets appended as i run the program rather than i manually change the names everyday and manully merge them to the previous  day's file.

Comment: @AP - Use `xlsread` to read from the old files, append the new data, and then call `xlswrite`, for the second problem.  This is (essentially) what gnovice suggested in his comment.